# A script to automatically split an Aperture library

Tags: applescript, photos.app, automator, aperture

My Aperture library contains a ridiculous amount of pictures (well over 30 000) which means it is extremely slow whatever the hard-drive and computer I use.

I want to split my library into separate libraries.  The split could be yearly or with a fixed number of pictures per library.

Should it be possible to do this automatically  (automator script, command line etc)?  If so, any suggestions how?

(This would probably be useful for iPhoto too)

My current solution is to use smart albums (but I encounter the difficulty of deleting the pictures:  [Delete all pictures in an album from library in Aperture](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101168/delete-all-pictures-in-an-album-from-library-in-aperture))

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem possible through Automator, but it could be through a little complex Applescript…

My personal approach was first gather various projects by context in folders (e.g. abroad holidays) and then - for each of them - export its content as an external library every 5 years. Hope this can apply to you!

O.T.: I'd like to post this as a comment, but it seems that I don't have enough reputation…